# Error loading @next/swc-win32-ia32-msvc in Next.js project: DLL initialization routine failed

Tags: node.js, next.js, node-modules

I'm encountering an issue in my Next.js project related to the loading of the @next/swc-win32-ia32-msvc module. The error message I'm getting is:

⚠ Attempted to load @next/swc-win32-ia32-msvc, but an error occurred: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\?\D:<project path>\node_modules@next\swc-win32-ia32-msvc\next-swc.win32-ia32-msvc.node
⨯ Failed to load SWC binary for win32/ia32, see more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc

I've followed the link provided in the error message, but I couldn't find a solution to this specific problem. I've also checked the official Next.js documentation, but it didn't provide a resolution.

**What I've Tried:**

1. **Reinstalling Dependencies:** I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the project dependencies using `npm install` to ensure that all modules, including `@next/swc-win32-ia32-msvc`, are up to date.
2. **Node.js Version:** I've verified that my Node.js version is compatible with the Next.js version I'm using, as recommended in the official documentation.
3. **Checking System Requirements:** I've reviewed the system requirements for Next.js and the associated modules, making sure my development environment meets the necessary criteria.
4. **Cleaning Node Modules:** I've cleared the `node_modules` directory and reinstalled dependencies to rule out any potential conflicts or corruption.
5. **Reviewing Next.js Documentation:** I've carefully reviewed the Next.js documentation related to the error message but couldn't find a solution specific to the "DLL initialization routine failed" issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the Windows 11 64-bit operating system. I installed node 32bit and saw the same error you have.
Here is what I did to solve the problem.

- First, I remove install node 32bit.
- [install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable chose 2015, 2017, 2019, and 2022 x64](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist)
- and then installed node 64bit and everything worked for me.

If you already have node 64 installed, you should install it  Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable